# How to add different classes to my validate() elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the validate jQuery method to validate this form:

```
<form id="emailRecover">    
    <div class="row light-field-container error-container">
        <input type="text" id="dniPassword" name="dniPassword" required="" class="form-text">
         <span class="tool-error">Please, insert your ID card number.</span>
         <div class="birthdate-input">
             <input type="text" id="birthdatePassword" required="" name="birthdatePassword" class="form-text">
             <span class="format">DD/MM/AA</span>
          </div>
          <span class="tool-error">Please, insert your birth date.</span>
          <input type="button" id="sendword-new-button" name="send_password_new_button" >
     </div>
 </form>
```

And I created the following **validate()** method for it:

```
$('#emailRecover').validate({ 
    errorPlacement: function () { },
    errorClass: 'form-text form-error',
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorElementClass: 'tool-error',
    rules: {
        dniPassword: {
            required: true
        },
        birthdatePassword: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

I want to add a custom class to my *error inputs*, something like this:

```
<form id="emailRecover">    
    <div class="row light-field-container error-container">
        <input type="text" id="dniPassword" name="dniPassword" required="" class="form-text form-error"> <-- Added class to this input
         <span class="tool-error">Please, insert your ID card number.</span>
         <div class="birthdate-input">
             <input type="text" id="birthdatePassword" required="" name="birthdatePassword" class="form-text form-error"> <-- Added class to this input
             <span class="format">DD/MM/AA</span>
          </div>
          <span class="tool-error">Please, insert your birth date.</span>
          <input type="button" id="sendword-new-button" name="send_password_new_button" >
     </div>
 </form>
```

But if I set my *errorClass: form-text form-error", then the labels and the spans also have this class, and then my styles are not applied.

How can I add my custom class only to the *input* field?

As an addition to the accepted answer, I could **unhighlight** the focused element by adding this to my validation rule:

```
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
         $(element.form).find('input[name='+$(':focus').attr('name')+']').removeClass("form-error");
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`highlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and [`unhighlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) properties like this:

```
$('form').validate({
    // make sure error message isn't displayed
    errorPlacement: function () { },
    // set the errorClass as a random string to prevent input disappearing when valid
    errorClass : "error_class_name",
    // use highlight and unhighlight
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.form).find("input").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.form).find("input").removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

> *`highlight`* - How to highlight invalid fields. Override to decide which fields and how to highlight.
>   *`unhighlight`* - Called to revert changes made by option highlight, same arguments as highlight.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect!! Now I'm trying to *unhighligh* only the one that has been highlighted before, not all of them as this code does :)

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you, Thanks!